# Is it possible to display upcoming posts in Wordpress blog page?

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to display upcoming posts in Wordpress 4+ blog page and how can I do that? I was searching everywhere and no answer for this version of Wordpress. Blog page only shows posts from the date before today and that's not what I want. I want to show posts that's, let's say scheduled for 2 months in a future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `post_status=future` with the standard Wordpress `query_posts`. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status

This is a simple example loop for 10 posts with error "no posts" message, title and date:

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=10&post_status=future'); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

<span class="datetime"><?php the_time('j. F Y'); ?></span></p>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<p>No future events scheduled.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This is probably more what you are looking for. It's a function that includes future posts on date archives and single posts. Put in the `functions.php` file of your theme:

```
if ( !is_admin() ) :
function __include_future( $query )
{
    if ( $query->is_date() || $query->is_single() )
        $GLOBALS[ 'wp_post_statuses' ][ 'future' ]->public = true;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', '__include_future' );
endif;
```

From https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16794/show-scheduled-posts-in-archive-page

> Essentially, it says, "If we're on a date archive, or viewing a single
>   post, make future posts publicly visible." As a result, WordPress
>   behaves normally when you view archives for any given date, except now
>   it also includes posts "from the future."